# MS Access SQL code in VBA is causing troubles

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Please can I ask that someone assist with the below SQL code.  I am trying to open a recordset based on a variable BUSINESSTERM.

My SQL string looks like this:

```
sqlstr = "SELECT TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID,         TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTerm, TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermDesc,     TblBusinessTerm.DomainCatID, " _
            & " TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermLongDesc,     TblBusinessTerm.DomainID, TblBusinessSynonym.UpdatedBusinessTerm, * " _
            & " FROM TblBusinessTerm LEFT JOIN TblBusinessSynonym ON     TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID = TblBusinessSynonym.BusinessTermID " _
            & " WHERE (TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID)= ; " & businessterm

Me.RecordSource = sqlstr
```

The issue is in the WHERE Statement. I keep on getting the error that I have to many parenthesis, and then when I remove the parenthesis I get an error

> Syntax missing operator

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: A semicolon is usually an end of statement indicator.  Try removing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID=" & businessterm
```

And better:

```
WHERE TblBusinessTerm.BusinessTermID=" & Nz(businessterm, 0)
```